# K&R C Programming Language Exercise 2-3 code returns rubbish

Tags: c, integer, hex, converters

I tried to write a solution from exercise 2-3. After compilation, it returns random numbers on output. I don't really understand where this issue is coming from.

Any help appreciated.

StackOverflow keeps asking for more details. The purpose of the program is listed in the code bellow.

More delails.

Purpose of the code:

Write the function htoi(s), which converts a string of hexa-
decimal digits (including an optional 0x or 0X) into its
equivalent integer value. The allowable digits are 0 through 9,
a through f, and A through F.

```
/*
 * Write the function htoi(s), which converts a string of hexa-
 * decimal digits (including an optional 0x or 0X) into its
 * equivalent integer value. The allowable digits are 0 through 9,
 * a through f, and A through F.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int hti(char s)
{
        const char hexlist[] = "aAbBcCdDeEfF";
        int answ = 0;
        int i;

        for (i=0; s != hexlist[i] && hexlist[i] != '\0'; i++)
                ;
        if (hexlist[i] == '\0')
                answ = 0;
        else
                answ = 10 + (i/2);
        return answ;
}

unsigned int htoi(const char s[])
{
        int answ;
        int power = 0;
        signed int i = 0;
        int viable = 0;
        int hexit;

        if (s[i] == '0')
        {
                i++;
                if (s[i] == 'x' || s[i] == 'X')
                        i++;
        }
        const int stop = i;

        for (i; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
                ;
        i--;

        while (viable == 0 && i >= stop)
        {
                if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
                {
                        answ = answ + ((s[i] - '0') * pow(16, power));
                }
                else
                {
                        hexit = hti(s[i]);
                        if (hexit == 0)
                                viable = 1;
                        else
                        {
                                hexit = hexit * (pow(16, power));
                                answ += hexit;
                        }
                }
                i--;
                power++;
        }
        if (viable == 1)
                return 0;
        else
                return answ;
}

int main()
{
        char test[] = "AC";
        int i = htoi(test);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: A debugger would be a good place to start.

Comment: In `hti` you return 0 for any ASCII hex digit that is '0' - '9'. Not sure if that's intended. The logic is very circuitous.

Comment: _it returns random numbers on output._, for which input?

Comment: `answ` is not initialized in `htoi`. Initialize it to 0.

You could have discovered this by tracing the code, either by stepping through it with a debugger and printing values of the variables as it goes or by inserting `printf` statements to show the values of variables. You should not use Stack Overflow as a debugging service to figure out your program. You can ask specific questions about how things in the C programming language work, for example, but you should isolate any question to a specific part of your program, not just post the whole program and expect other people to debug it.

Comment: The loop body in `hti()` is empty, but should probably include the `if` statement as the body (preferably enclosed in braces).  Don't use `pow()` in integer calculations.  It would probably be better to adapt `hti()` so that it returns the correct value for any hex digit rather than have half the code (the part handling decimal digits) in `htoi()` and the other half (handling hex letters) in `hti()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The code would break if the `if` following that `for` loop were made the body of the loop (that is, if the `;` of the current empty body were deleted).

Comment: @EricPostpischil — yes, I agree that the empty loop body is okay given the code; that was my mistake.  My other comments ("no `pow()`", "not splitting duties") stand, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`answ` is not initialized in `htoi`. Initialize it to zero.